# Rails method to iterate through hash of photos and return value according to criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, hashmap, instagram-api

I want to create a method (ruby on rails) to iterate through a hash of photos I am pulling from an API (url, name, date created etc) and return only the dates that are in the correct params the user inputs. Inside of the hash you have `created_time` as one of the keys, and that is what I am interested in. Any suggestions?

```
def pull_time
  @pictures.map do |picture|
    if picture.created_time >= @start_date && picture.created_time <= @end_date
      return @pictures
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: dou you want a all the pictures which is follow the above condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`between`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/between%3F):

```
@pictures.select { |picture| picture.created_time.between?(@start_date, @end_date) }
```